# Hibernate mappings with spring rest api

Tags: spring, hibernate, rest

Hi I am trying the make the hibernate mappings work with the rest api application. I have two entities named Patient and appointments and they have @oneToMany relation (one patient can have many apointments)

here is the patient class:

`@Entity
@Table(name = "Patient_info")
public class Patient {

```
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
private int patientId;
private String patientName;
private int age;
private LocalDate dateOfBirth;
private String contactNumber;
private String address;

@OneToMany(mappedBy="patient", cascade=CascadeType.ALL)
private List<Appointment> appointments;

@OneToMany(mappedBy="patient", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
private List<MedicalRecord> medicalRecords;
```

}`

and here is the appointment class:

`@Entity
@Table(name="Appointment_info")
public class Appointment {

```
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
private int appointmentId;

private LocalDate date;
private LocalTime time;
private String symptoms;
private String visitType;
private String status;

@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name="doctor_Id")
private Doctor doctor;

@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name = "patient_Id")
private Patient patient;
```

}`

With this mapping i have a appointment table with foriegn keys to patient and doctor

this is the service class function for the patient

```
public boolean scheduleAppointment(AppointmentDto appointmentDto) {
                Appointment appointment = new Appointment();
        appointment.setStatus("pending");
        appointment.setDate(appointmentDto.getDate());
        appointment.setSymptoms(appointmentDto.getSymptoms());
        appointment.setVisitType(appointmentDto.getVisitType());
        appointmentRepository.save(appointment);
        return true;
}`

so how do i associate this appointment with the patient that is scheduling the appointment?
    

in the json when i pass the parameters it's showing the patient id and doctorid and null in the table
```